# Comparing document timestamps in Firestore rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm running into a weird problem while writing and testing my Firestore rules. Here's what I want to achieve:

- When the application starts, the user gets logged in anonymously. The
  user starts a new game.
- I create a 'Session' that basically consists of just a timestamp.
- The player plays the game, gets a certain highscore and goes to a screen where the score can be sent to the global highscore list. When the highscore is submitted, I check if there's an existing session for this player and if the time that has passed is long enough for the highscore to be considered valid.

On the client (javascript) I use the following line to send the timestamp in my  documents:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

This is the current ruleset. You can see that a score can only be created when the createdAt of the new higscore is later than the createdAt of the session.

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        function isValidNewScoreEntry() {
            return request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['createdAt', 'name', 'score']) &&
            request.resource.data.createdAt is timestamp &&
            request.resource.data.name is string &&
            request.resource.data.score is int &&
            request.resource.data.name.size() <= 20
        }

        match /highscores/{entry} {
            allow list: if request.query.limit <= 10;
            allow get: if true; 
            allow create: if isValidNewScoreEntry() &&
      request.resource.data.createdAt > get(/databases/$(database)/documents/sessions/$(request.auth.uid)).data.createdAt;
        }

        function isValidNewSession() {
            return request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['createdAt']) &&
            request.resource.data.createdAt is timestamp
        }

        match /sessions/{entry} {
            allow list: if false;
            allow get: if false; 
            allow create: if isValidNewSession();
            allow update: if isValidNewSession();
        }
    }
}
```

When I simulate/test these rules, I get an error that says that I cannot compare a 'timestamp' to a 'map'. I don't know why the 'createdAt' value is a map, but it seems like the get() method returns something different than expected.

My question is: What would be the correct way to compare the property **createdAt** from the newly submitted entry to the property **createdAt** of the existing session document, like I'm trying to do in the rules described above.

[This is what a'Score' entry look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXsLt.png)
[This is what a 'Session' entry looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H87WA.png)

**EDIT:**

I've done some more digging, and found that this line works:

`if request.resource.data.createdAt.toMillis() > get(/databases/$(database)/documents/sessions/$(request.auth.uid)).data.createdAt.seconds * 1000;`

This makes it pretty clear that not both createdAt are the same format. The last one seems to be a basic object with the properties 'seconds' and 'nanoseconds'. I'm sure it stems from the Timestamp interface, but it gets returned as a flat object since [none of the methods found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) exist and give an error when trying to call them. The property 'seconds' however does exists on the second timestamp, but is not accessible on the first one.

Comment: I don't understand what this means: *"For some reason the second timestamp gets converted to a 'map'"*. What exactly are you observing here?  I also don't understand what your rule is trying to prevent.

Comment: When I try to test the rule, it gives me an error that I can only do the ' > ' compare when the two values are of the same type, but that right now an error says I'm comparing a 'timestamp' to a 'map'. I think this is because the get() call gives me some JSON equivalent of the timestamp instead of an actual timestamp.

What I'm trying to do is compare if the submitted score createdAt is at least later than the start of a game session's createdAt.

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly the contents of the database that you're trying to compare.  It sounds like your document doesn't actually contain a proper timestamp in the createdAt field.

Comment: I can't add images since this is my first post ever. But I've added links to images to the post. As you can see, both documents do have a valid timestamp. They are created the exact same way, with the FieldValue.serverTimestamp() as 'createdAt'. I'm not quite sure what the get() method returns inside the ruleset, but it does not give me the timestamp the way I would expect.

Comment: Maybe you should edit the question to show the entire ruleset, and also the code the performs the write.  I'm still not clear on the problem you're trying to solve.  Minimizing the code to one line doens't help.  Anyone reading the question should be able to duplicate what you're doing with minimal trouble.  Also please explain how you know that something is being converted to a map.

Comment: I've added the whole ruleset and a step by step of what I'm trying to do. Hopefully this helps

Comment: You say you're using the simulator.  What exactly are you entering into the simulator that causes the problem?  The simulator is also known to have bugs.  Have you tried this with an actual query?

Comment: I'm replicating the exact same thing I would when creating a new highscore document. I have not tried an actual query, since this project is being tested by other people and I can't just change the database rules without the game breaking. I've added new info to the post with some new findings.

Comment: Without testing the actual product, it's hard to say what is going on.  You could always file a bug report and make it clear that you're using the simulator.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: I found the problem. When using `get()` within rules, you don't get a document, but a `Resource`. `Resources` have the same `data` property, but this is in fact a `Map`, so not at all what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out why the timestamp is not what I expected and got cast to a 'map'.
After digging through the documentation I found that the `get()` method returns a `resource`. `resource` has a property `data`: a map. So the `get()` method does not return a document as I expected but a flat JSON object that gives me all properties found in de database.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource

Comment: So, what did you do to change your rules to make them work?